# Cron job not running in CentOS

Tags: linux, cron, centos

I have a script `abc.sh` which runs a command to generate a csv file and send an email. This script runs fine when I manually execute it.
I have added the following entry to my crontab using `crontab -e` command:

```
00 18 * * * /home/abc.sh
```

However, this cron job does not execute at all.
I checked

```
service crond status
```

and the CRON service is running.

Am I missing some permissions?

Comment: Is your script really directly under the `/home` directory? Try a simple entry like `* * * * * touch CRON_IS_RUNNING`. Did you try running the script manually? Cron jobs run with a limited set of environment variables (`man 5 crontab` for details). Most likely your `abc.sh` depends on some environment variable that's available in your interactive shell but not exported to cron jobs.

Comment: most probably you need to add the binary running it: `00 18 * * * /bin/sh /home/abc.sh`

Comment: Adding the /bin/sh worked. Also, turns out the cron job was not able to read the path of the jar file listed in my command. Thanks.